# YAMLError: mapping values

Tags: python, cloud

I'm trying to deploy my python file using dev_appserver.py on my Mac and i keep getting this reply

"google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventListenerYAMLError: mapping values are not allowed here:
 in "serial_lambda.py", line 8, column 17"
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import httplib

runs = 5
count = 100

def serial_run():
    for x in range(0, runs):
    try:
      c = httplib.HTTPSConnection("")
      json= '{ "key1": ' + str(count) + '}'
      c.request("POST", "/"deploy", json)
      response = c.getresponse()
      data = response.read()

      print data
    except IOError, e:
     print 'Failed to open "%s".'% host

start = time.time()
serial_run()
print "Elapsed Time %s" (time.time() - start)
```

Not sure how to correct it. Any suggestions?